# Tab bar controller gray boxes in xcode 6

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6

Can anyone tell me why these gray boxes appear in my tab bar controller? A while ago I was seeing dummy tab bar icons, but now they're just gray boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Add an image again** to your `Tab Bar Item` after rebooting Xсode.

When you set an image to every single `Tab Bar Item` the `Tab Bar` will be shown normally.

Thats works for me. And it seems like this is the only solution.

[image: Image to tab bar item]